# html2canvas and dompdf getting blank image source

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html2canvas

I am using [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) and [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).

I am trying to convert a div into image and transfer that image via ajax. Then in my server side code I am processing that image into pdf. I am using dompdf in creating a pdf.
This is my code:

```
 html2canvas(jQuery("#try_screenshot"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    jQuery("#screenshot").html("<img src='"+image+"' />");
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/order/send-email.php",
                        dataType: "json",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                            src: image
                        },
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

This is my `send-email.php` code.

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
if(isset($_POST['src'])){

    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $imgsrc = $_POST['src'];

    $dompdf->loadHtml("<img src='$imgsrc' />");


    // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    $file_name = time().".pdf";
    file_put_contents("pdfs/".$file_name, $output);
}
```

My problem here is that i am getting a blank pdf file.

I tried accessing the `image` src in the browser and I can see it saying `This site can’t be reached`. **But** actually it isn't because I have this code `jQuery("#screenshot").html("<img src='"+image+"' />");` and I can see the image right away appending in my html div.

The image is encoded in base64. Here is a link of a sample base64 image. This is not the full base64 image text because SO wouldn't let me put all of those because I exceeded 30k words.

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I am banging my heads for 2 days already.

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: why aren't you using formData?\

Comment: @madalinivascu sorry, how would I do that? Do you have a guide for me please. Thanks.

Comment: here is the basics https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: I have the same issue and i cant understand how can i fix this to....